# HttpClient read file takes a lot of time

Tags: android, httpclient

I am currently facing some speed problem and want to know how can i reduce it to reasonable time.

So, i have a csv file in my server about 12mb and holds about 21.000 lines
i am currently connecting server and read html output line by line which gives me about 17 minutes wait to complete.

I really appreciate for any help get faster like 4 minutes or so.

Here is my current code

```
HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(downloadURL);
HttpResponse response = myClient.execute(httpget); // Execute
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);

String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
String[] splitData = line.split("\\,");
...
...
...
```

Regards

Comment: I think it depends on internet speed, and server side issues can make these problems. Server vary in different situation.

Comment: Have you looked into compressing the file?

Comment: Connection speed is 65mpbs (with wifi) i want to know that HttpClient connect to server to read each line? How exactly given code works?